# Java GUI: Objects and Label are not visible

Tags: java, user-interface, label

I've intended to create a simple gui that would draw an oval in the top third of the window, display a name in the middle third, and draw a rectangle in the bottom third(to be done later)

So far, the only parts I've been able to create and make visible are four buttons that are eventually meant to toggle the visibility of the objects and label.

The problem I'm having is that I cannot get the label or the oval to appear, and I'm not sure what I'm missing preventing either to be visble

```js
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


public class Gui extends JFrame
 implements ActionListener
{
 private JButton bottomLeftButton;
 private JButton bottomMiddleLeftButton;
 private JButton bottomRightButton;
 private JButton bottomMiddleRightButton;
 private OtherPanel mypanel;
 private JLabel name;
 private JPanel panelOne;
 private boolean visible;
 
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
 {
  if(e.getSource() == bottomLeftButton)
  {
   visible = name.isVisible();
   name.setVisible(visible);
  }
  else if(e.getSource() == bottomMiddleLeftButton)
  {
   
  }
  else if (e.getSource() == bottomMiddleRightButton)
  {
   
  }
  else if (e.getSource() == bottomRightButton)
  {
   
  }
  repaint();
 }
 public Gui()
 {
  setTitle("First GUI");
  setSize(800,800);
  setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  
  Container contentPane = this.getContentPane();
  contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
  
  JPanel BottomPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,4));
  contentPane.add(BottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
  
  bottomLeftButton = new JButton("Name");
  bottomLeftButton.addActionListener(this);
  BottomPanel.add(bottomLeftButton);
  
  bottomMiddleLeftButton = new JButton("Oval");
  bottomMiddleLeftButton.addActionListener(this);
  BottomPanel.add(bottomMiddleLeftButton);
  
  bottomMiddleRightButton = new JButton("Square");
  bottomMiddleRightButton.addActionListener(this);
  BottomPanel.add(bottomMiddleRightButton);
  
  bottomRightButton = new JButton("Special");
  bottomRightButton.addActionListener(this);
  BottomPanel.add(bottomRightButton);
  
  JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
  centerPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
  
  panelOne = new OtherPanel();
  
  name = new JLabel("Name");
  name.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
  
  JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Label3");
  
  centerPanel.add(panelOne);
  centerPanel.add(name);
  centerPanel.add(label3);
  
 }
 
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  Gui gui = new Gui();
  gui.setVisible(true);
 }
}
```

(meant to draw the oval)

```js
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class OtherPanel extends JPanel
{
 public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
 {
  int x = 10;
  int y = 10;
  int width = getWidth(); //ten pixels of spaces
  int height = getHeight();
  g.fillOval(x, y, width, height);
 }
}
```

Comment: Call revalidate followed by repainted when adding/removing components; call super.paintComponent before you do any custom painting; override getPreferredSize to provide sizing hints for the layout manager

Comment: ..or you should `pack()` your gui instance before setting it visible.

Answer (score 0):

was missing a line of code to add the objects to the contentPane

contentPane.add(centerPanel); goes at the end of the gui() method